# Convert array of strings into array of objects in R

Tags: arrays, r, variables, object

Let's say I have these 3 objects

```
first<-1
second<-"hello"
third<-3
```

And I have an array of characters like this:

```
example<-c("first","second","third")
```

How can I automatically convert all the names in the array to the object with the same name? In order to have something like:

```
example2<-c(first, second, third)
```

I know there are similar questions but I can't find any answer which I can make work for my case too.
Thank you to whoever may help

UPDATE:

If I do:

```
example3<-mget(example)
```

ant then type `example2` and `example3` in the R console, the outputs are slightly different.

```
> example2
[1] "1"     "hello" "3"   

> example3
$first
[1] 1

$second
[1] "hello"

$third
[1] 3
```

I need example3 to be exactly the same object as example2, because if I run `cbind(example3)` I get some error, while `cbind(example2)` works fine, but the array of objects is the same.
Of course in my code the objects named first, second and third are of a different kind than in this post, but the logic is the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is `sapply(example, get)` what you're after?

Comment: `example = mget(…)`.

Comment: Thank you both @tonytonov and @konrad. I think with those two commands I don't exactly get the same array of objects as **example2**. In fact the example2 output in R is
`> example2
[1] "1"     "hello" "3"` 
while the **example3** output after running `example3=mget(example)` is:
`> example3
$first
[1] 1
$second
[1] "hello"
$third
[1] 3`
and this causes problems with cbind.  `cbind(example2)` works, while with `cbind(example3)` I get the error _(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'_.
Of course the _first_, _second_ and _third_ objects are different in my real code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your recent comment, and the suggestion of Konrad Rudolph, I believe you are looking for

```
unlist(mget(example), use.names = FALSE)
# [1] "1"     "hello" "3"
```